# JBoss EAP 7.2.0 installation won't start

Tags: java, jboss, windows-10, virtualbox, jboss7.x

I downloaded JBoss EAP 7.2.0 installer from RedHat pages, put the installer to my VirtualBox with Windows 10 and tried to doubleclick on the installer to open it via my Java 8. Nothing happens.

Did anyone have similar issue? Is there any possible way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest java 8 version solved the problem.